# Using Failover Clustering

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about failover clustering.  If I set up failover clustering with 4 nodes and each node has a different instance of SQL Server running on it, will I need four separate licenses?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing issues.

Comment: Would you like me to remove it?

Comment: Yes, or we do it. Read the licenses you have - we do not deal with the legal aspect of licensing on stackoverflow. Many reasons, one that this would be legal advice.

Comment: I can't delete it now because it has answers.  Please take it down if you like, and I'm sorry for any trouble I caused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to have separate licensing